# Get all configuration from a namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
<?php namespace World;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TMissionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = false;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['mission'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            # $config = How to array of package config?

            return new Mission($config);
        });
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package(null, 'mission', realpath(__DIR__. '/../'));
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array('mission');
    }
}
```

How do I get the returned array from my `mission/config.php`?

```
<?php

return array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'leader' => 'Mother Theresa'
);
```

It returns the proper value when I do

```
dd($app['config']->get('mission::host')); # 127.0.0.1
```

but when I do

```
dd($app['config']->get('mission'));  # array() empty
```

it returns an empty array.

Comment: Where exactly is this `mission/config.php` file?

Comment: `app/config/packages/mission/config.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the actual file name. Try something like this.

```php
$app['config']->get('mission::config');
```

In this case `config` is referring to the file, so it should return the entire array.

Comment: Can package configurations be put into separate environments as well?